# Fortran Equivalence

Tags: fortran, equivalence

I want to use `Equivalence`. How can it be used in gfortran-5?

I am using:

```fortran
Select Case (dst)
Case ("cm")
  Equivalence :: (cm2Mm_r32, r32), (cm2Mm_r64, r64)
  Call qcdiv (qb, qa, r32, r64, cm2Mm_r128)
Case ("m")
  Equivalence :: (m2Mm_r32, r32), (m2Mm_r64, r64)
  Call qcdiv (qb, qa, r32, r64, m2Mm_r128)
Case ("Km")
  Equivalence :: (Km2Mm_r32, r32), (Km2Mm_r64, r64)
  Call qcdiv (qb, qa, r32, r64, Km2Mm_r128)
End Select
```

Comment: Don't.  Just don't.  Drink yourself to oblivion, regard the hangover you suffer from in the morning as a just punishment for thinking of using `equivalence`.  Luckily for you `equivalence` is a type of declaration and can't be positioned where you want it.

Comment: What would be the way to have two names for a variable?

Comment: From what I gather there are at least two objections to using `equivalence`: 1) it makes code harder to read, since an outsider wouldn't necessarily know that two variables refer to the same bit of memory, 2) you can interpret the `equivalenced` bit of memory as different types, which isn't very sensible.

Comment: yes, `equivalence` is that bad.  Likely it only still exists to support legacy code.     You could have multiple names for a variable with pointers.  Why?

Comment: I am using two unlimited polymorphic variables to handle general numerical conversions and I am ending up with an extremely long subroutine. I wanted to use shorter variables for the conversion factors by setting them according to the conversion taking place. To simplify I have to handle the polymorphic checking by creating another subroutine and calling that with the correct conversion factor.

Comment: If just the names are too long, use `associate`, if you do not need it to be `allocatable` or `pointer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equivalence statement must be positioned in the declaration part. You cannot control it with conditionals.

Modern Fortran prefers `transfer()` to convert bit patterns. If you do not need type conversions, use pointers.

I actually use equivalence in one place of my code, where the Intel compiler is unable to optimize the `transfer()`, but that is an exception, you should think twice before using it.

Comment: I do need type conversions. I have now found a neat solution without equivalence, transfer or pointers.

Comment: What is that solution? There is a chance that it will contravene some restriction of the Fortran standard and will be liable to break under optimization. Many type punning tricks have that problem.

Comment: It is here https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/508330 . Notice my comment in the code fearing the equivalence. I now compilers can do byte swapping under some flags, but I wanted to have it under my control and only for specific files.